# Loading animation depending on location

Tags: angularjs

I'm using chieffancypants angular-loading-bar for my app (https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar).
I just have a question how to enable loading bar and loading spinner for seperate locations?
For example if I want to see loading bar only in some.html and spinner in other.html?
I'm asking this, because in documentation

```
$http.get('/status', {
ignoreLoadingBar: true
});
```

ignores both spinner and loader, and I can't find a way to change cfpLoadingBarProvider inerceptors depending on location. 
Some guidance would be appreciated.